# How do I execute a shell command path after creating a new directory in Makefile?

Tags: java, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to get an updated path of my variable service_SOURCES, after I have generated some files from jaxb with my makefile:

```
service.jar$(EXEEXT): $(service_SOURCES)
    mkdir -p bin
    xjc -d src -p gen.files ./src/resources/info.xsd
    javac -cp service_SOURCES

service_SOURCES := $(shell find ./src -name "*.java")
```

I am trying to compile my existing java code with my generated java code Currently, my service_SOURCES variable finds my folder containing my java files, and compiles them all together. I need it to update to include the newly generated java folder, so it compiles my new java files along with my old java files.

I've tried linking the above commands together using && but the shell command still doesn't update. If I run the above commands in terminal it works, but when I run it in my Makefile the path won't update properly.

Comment: What do you mean, "update"? You're on extremely shaky ground if you are counting on a `make` variable taking different values at different times during the same execution of `make`.  If you insist on that, however, then a *simply-expanded* variable certainly seems an odd choice for the job.  In any case, you've got a much better chance of getting a useful answer if you provide an [mcve] that more clearly demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: When I mean update, I mean I have a variable whose value I don't want executed until after I have generated my java files. So after I generate my java files with the xjc command, I want to compile my previous code w/generated code at the location stored by service_SOURCES, which finds the paths of the java files using a shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving to answer as this doesn't fit in comment)

You should understand that Make runs in two phases -- The dependency tree is built in the first phase, and the rules are run in the second.   This means that the dependency tree cannot be updated by a shell command run after files are generated by a recipe.   If you want to do something like this (and I agree with @JohnBollinger, this might not be the best idea), you might need to split your logic between two makefiles, or have a self-recursive makefile.   Either way you need to generate the files, then call the second makefile, which can then build a new dependency tree based on a timely shell command.

Alternative:

```
service.jar$(EXEEXT): _target_to_generate_java_files_
    mkdir -p bin
    xjc -d src -p gen.files ./src/resources/info.xsd
    javac -cp $$(find ./src -name "*.java")
```

Comment: I see, thank you. I wasn't sure if I had to generate the files first, since I saw people were able to create a directory and then update their directory path afterwards. I had assumed I could do the same.